# Why was the character of Chief O'Hara created

Tags: character, batman-1966

In the 1966 [***Batman***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059968/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt) TV series, the vast majority of characters, heroes and villains both, already existed in the comics (or were close versions of pre-existing characters).

However, Chief Miles Clancy O'Hara (played by Stafford Repp) was completely new character.

[image]

**Is there any reference as to why the character was created for the series?**

Comment: [" The character was created by Semple for the series, as someone for Gordon to talk to"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(TV_series)#Cast)

Comment: @BCdotWEB Sounds like an answer if it is sourced